# por que me aparece este error en visual studio C#?

Tags: c#

hola me aparece este error y no se que me olvide de instalar en visual estudio para que me aparezca [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que eso de debe a que se te está duplicando la clase persona al compilar, lo que tienes que hacer es ir a la carpeta de tu proyecto `bin/debug` y asegurarte de que no este duplicada

Comment: Has incluido `Persona.cs` en tu proyecto? Viendo la imagen de tu `Explorador de soluciones` se observa que dicho archivo está establecido en tu archivo de proyecto pero no se encuentra en la ruta especificada.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que ir a la raíz del proyecto , abrir el .csprj y borrar esta línea :

```
<ItemGroup>
 <Compile Include="carpeta\Namespace\persona.cs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

En algún momento habrás tocado las propiedades de esa clase.